# Disable TouchableHighlight until I submit the form

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react native project, the user need to enter his basic details to move forward into the application ,so as a part of validation i want to disable the touchable highlight until the user fill all the form details( here in my case i am using  react native picker for making user comfortable to fill the form )how can i disable the touchablehighlight until the user selects all the picker values ?
Can some one help me with that?
Following is the sample code of my project.

```
<View>
  <Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.bloodgrp}
    style={{ height: 50, width: 170, color: 'black' }}
    baseColor="#FFF" //for initial text color
    onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({bloodgrp: itemValue})}>
    <Picker.Item label="Select" value='Select' />
    <Picker.Item label="A+" value='A+' />
    <Picker.Item label="A-" value='A-' />
    <Picker.Item label="B+" value='B+' />
    <Picker.Item label="B-" value='B-' />
    <Picker.Item label="O+" value='O+' />
    <Picker.Item label="O-" value='O-' />
    <Picker.Item label="AB+" value='AB+' />
    <Picker.Item label="AB-" value='AB-' />
</Picker>
</View>

<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Gender :</Text>
  <Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.gender}
    style={{ height: 50, width: 170, color: 'black' }}
    baseColor="#FFF" //for initial text color
    onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({gender: itemValue})}>
    <Picker.Item label="Select" value=''/>
    <Picker.Item label="Male" value='Male' />
    <Picker.Item label="Female" value='Female' />
  </Picker>
</View>

<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
  <Text style={styles.textLabel}>Height :</Text>
  <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
    <Picker
      selectedValue={this.state.height}
      style={{ height: 50, width: 150, color: 'black'}}
      baseColor="#FFF" //for initial text color
      onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({height: itemValue})}>
      <Picker.Item label="Select"  value='' />
      <Picker.Item label="121.92" value='121.92' />
      <Picker.Item label="124.46" value='124.46' />
      <Picker.Item label="127.00" value='127.00' />
    </Picker>
    <TouchableHighlight
      underlayColor={ 'rgb(32, 53, 70)'}
      activeOpacity={0.9}>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get your BMI</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
</View>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you try `TouchableWithoutFeedback`

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        bloodgrp: undefined,
        height: undefined,
        gender: undefined,
    }
}


<TouchableHighlight 
    disabled ={!(this.state.bloodgrp && this.state.height && this.state.gender)}
</TouchableHighlight >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        disabledBtn: true
    };
}

render() {
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.disabledBtn}>
            <Text>Click</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

**Now you can change the disabledBtn state for enable it on any action or event 
let me know if still facing issue  **

Comment: Hi Anil, I want the button to be in a disabled state until the user fills the form. Once he selects all the options from the picker the button should come into active state .can u pls help me out with that?

Comment: use a function to check all your form validation and if all validations are true than make true to disabledBtn state. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qn4rJ1RMWBk
this video may help you to make form validations.